# How do I add Facebook OpenGraph meta tags for attachments in the header for a custom theme?

Tags: attachments, headers, facebook, wp-head, open-graph

How do I add Facebook OpenGraph tags in the header when the header has already been called, and the values I need to add are obtained in the body? This is a highly customized theme (which I did not create).

Here is the `image.php` file which contains the attachment page for an image:

```
  <div class="posted-att">
    <?php 
      echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment_id,'large');
```

I don't know where `$attachment_id` is set. It's not set in `image.php`. It's set in several places in `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` but I'm not sure which ones are relevant.

I tried adding the following to `header.php`, but `$attachment_id` was `null`/`0`.

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>

<?php echo 'attachment id = ' . $attachment_id; ?>
<?php if ($attachment_id != null) : // Facebook OpenGraph
  $shareImage = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment_id); ?>
  <meta property="og:image" content="<?=$shareImage?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

I also found this http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-facebook-open-graph-meta-data-in-wordpress-themes/, but my posts don't have featured images. I'm trying to share specific attached images.

Answer (score 0):

$attachment_id is simply the numerical ID assigned to any media you have uploaded. You can write:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image('1','large');
```

to display the large size of image attachment with ID of 1.

You should setup a new query to get all of the attachment IDs associated with the current post, then you can

```
get_posts('post_type=attachment')
```

Check this example and modify the li's to become the meta property declaration instead: [codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image#Display_all_images_as_a_list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image#Display_all_images_as_a_list)

Answer (score 0):

You can get all images attached to the current post with something like this :

```
$images = get_posts(
        array(
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
            'post_parent'    => $post->ID, // the current post id
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
        )
    );
```

Your theme is most likely just using the first attachment or something similar.